# What's the nicest way to add custom functions to an external library's class in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a number of helper functions based on other people's libraries. One example is that I want to convert a glm::vec3 to a glm::vec2.

Ideally, I would make the constructor

```
glm::vec2(glm::vec3 v)
```

which would allow me to assign a vec3 onto a vec2, but I dont *think* you can add custom constructors to an external library.

Alternatively,

```
v.ToVec2()
```

would be adequate, but again I don't *think* you can add custom methods...

The only other thing I can think is just a basic function

```
a = Vec3ToVec2(glm::vec3 v)
```

but it seems less clean.

What would you suggest??

Comment: You cannot change existing classes that way. Inheritance may be possible sometimes.

Comment: You probably could also do some operator overload magic, but I find that to be even worse.

Comment: So does it seem the best way is just to use a function?

Comment: There is nothing "less clean" about freeing yourself from the shackles of object-obessiveness.

Comment: @MaxPeglar-Willis _"Why do people always downvote questions on here?"_ Because _"What would you suggest??"_ clearly asks for opinions, and that's _off-topic_ here.

Comment: "seems less clean" in this case is a feeling you get when you are not familiar with enough examples of this being done, which could indicate a blind spot. `vecutils::vec3_to_vec2(glm::vec3 v);` isn't particularly out of the ordinary, although could probably be better named and definitely requires a documentation comment at the very least.

Comment: Why do you need this? [`glm::vec2`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00020.html) already has a constructor that takes a `glm::vec3` as argument.